# Apple Mac Airplay "Unable to establish Connection"

Tags: airplay

I have a projector which I am trying to use with a MiraScreen Wireless HDMI adapter so that I can wirelessly use the projector from my computer.

I was able to get it working with Windows but when I click the Airplay icon on a Mac-book Air running Mac OS 10.9.5 after connecting to the MiraScreen Wifi AP, it says "Unable to establish connection."

I have the MiraScreen Module set to Apple/Airplay mode so that cannot be the problem. I have restarted the computer and tried to reconnect more than once without success.

Here is a link to the module I am using: [Module.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018JWYECA)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unlike AirPlay Audio (formerly AirTunes), I don't think Apple has ever documented AirPlay Screen Mirroring or licensed it to other device makers. So this vendor probably reverse engineered the protocol but maybe didn't do such a good job. Take it up with the module manufacturer.

Comment: I found that setting up a simple IPV6 on my network totally eliminated any airplay issues that we used to have. Sounds like the Mirascreen module could need a firmware update.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I believe you are right about the firmware update.... I still can't get it working.I would close this but I dont have enough rep.